# Select string by file extension

Tags: ruby, string

I have a comma separated string, that contains two URL's, like so:

```
"http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/45b3ab5f-9cb2-4696-91ea-5e2b8a3ef84d/c2aaecbaddfbd246c2b36d3e03144aad.mp4, http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/45b3ab5f-9cb2-4696-94ea-5e2b8a3ef84d/ca503efd6e59f2e887a1c52a14024v6e.webm"
```

I'd like to write a method that allows me to get the webm URL, as well as the mp4 URL – based on their file extension (not position... sometimes the position changes).

I'm wondering how I can select the full URL of each value by its file extension, using Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the string using [`String#split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-split) and filter out desired one using [`Array#select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-select):

```
s = "http://bucket....aad.mp4, http://bucket...v6e.webm" 
urls = s.split(',')
urls.select { |url| url.end_with? '.mp4' }  # `String#end_with?` to match extension
# => ["http://bucket....aad.mp4"]
```

Comment: How can I remove the surrounding brackets?

Comment: @cmw, `Array#select` returns an array. You can use `[]`: `urls.select { |url| url.end_with? '.mp4' }[0]` to get the first item.